# Swift DateFormatter could not produce date from string on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format a string(ex. Tue, 16 Jan 2018 | 05:34 PM) to date and then convert it back to string(ex. 2018-01-16 17:34:00) with different format by using following code.

```
let dateFormatterOne = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterOne.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyy | hh:mm a"
dateFormatterOne.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let dateFromString = dateFormatterOne.date(from: string)

let dateFormatterTwo = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterTwo.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateString = dateFormatterTwo.string(from: dateFromString!)
```

This seems to be working well in simulator but when I tested it on an iPod Touch running iOS 9 it doesn't give date in the first conversion so it becomes nil and crashes.

Comment: What is the locale on the iOS 9 device? If it's not set to English it will fail.

Comment: Set Current locale to English 
  dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!

Comment: it's still producing nil after I added the line dateFormatterOne.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")... does it matter if i put it before or after setting dateFormat

Comment: Try `"EEE, d MMM yyyy | hh:mm a"`. The order of setting the locale and format shouldn't matter but it can't hurt to try both ways.

Comment: i did but still the same result

Comment: Is it possible the string has some extra whitespace such as a newline? As `print("\"\(string)\"")` and see if there is anything unexpected.

Comment: it's not that either but I solved it by programmatically extracting each part from the string and making a new date from that using DateComponents() instance.